Dynamic references with \zcref
My objective is to have the following mechanism for numbering \item in enumerate inside a theorem environment.

When a new theorem wasn't issued yet (e.g. in the proof of the current theorem), then \item should be referenced as (i), (ii), etc.
When a new theorem was issued, subsequent references to \item should say the theorem number as well its type, e.g. theorem 1(i), etc.

The following might serve as a starting point:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{zref-clever}

\setlist[enumerate, 1]{label=(\roman*)}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\makeatletter
\zref@newprop{current@theorem}{\thetheorem}
\zref@addprop{main}{current@theorem}
\newcommand{\insert@theorem}[1]{%
    \ifthenelse{ \equal{\thetheorem}{\zref@extract{current@theorem}{#1}} }
        {}{\zref@extract{current@theorem}{#1}}%
}

\zcRefTypeSetup{subtheorem}{
    name-sg = theorem,
    Name-sg = Theorem,
    name-pl = theorems,
    Name-pl = Theorems,
    refbounds = {,???,,}
}

\AddToHook{env/theorem/begin}{%
    \zcsetup{ countertype = {enumi=subtheorem} }%
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem} \label{thm}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item \label{itm}
    \end{enumerate}
\end{theorem}

Input: \verb|\zcref{itm}|

Output: \zcref{itm}

Desired: (i)

\begin{theorem} \end{theorem}

Input: \verb|\zcref{itm}|

Output: \zcref{itm}

Desired: theorem 1(i)

\paragraph{Regarding sorting}\par

Input: \verb|\zcref{thm,itm}|

Output: \zcref{thm,itm}

Desired: theorems 1~and~1(i)

\end{document}


Since \item is referenced differently from theorem, I created a new type subtheorem.

If the theorem counter hasn't changed, then (i) is desired.
If the theorem counter has changed, then theorem 1(i) is desired.

The helper command \insert@theorem accepts a key like itm and could be used to provide the desired behaviour.
Moreover, both types subtheorem and theorem should be compatible when sorting, which aren't at the moment.

Note: This serves as a continuation of my question and answer here. This could help.

I'm having quite a hard time understanding what you are trying to do, which suggests that this would probably be taxing on the readers of the document too. Anyway, as far as I do, the condition depends on the position of the reference (a call to \zcref) relative to a certain document element (theorem). So there's no way you'd be able to test the condition on the label data alone, given that \label does not know where it will be referenced. Hence, you need some sort of wrapper reference command to test your condition. You can reference some other property with \zcref [...]

[...] with the ref option, but that is manual. There's no way for \zcref to guess your condition and use a different property automatically as it is built.

@gusbrs Thx for the cool package, btw. Anyway: I don't think that it's to difficult to understand. Many math books do something similar, although with chapter/theorem instead of theorem/item (e.g. theorem 2.1.1 vs. theorem I/2.1.1).

@gusbrs I hoped that the refbounds option would allow for passing the raw reference key (given as \label{<key>}) to the prerefentry, e.g. as refbounds={,\test{#1},,}. And that still doesn't solve the problem with dynamic printing of ref=name for \zcref.

Well, it may be my fault for not being acquainted with the style. About using refbounds for this... perhaps it might work... but this kind of thing definitely was not what this option was thought for. Usually this kind of difference would be worked storing both 1(i) and (i) with the label as different properties, as is done for subfigure etc. Also, even if you can work that out, you have another problem there in creating subtheorem as you do. As you noticed, it does not group with theorem, it is not sorted or compressed together. [...]

[...] zref-clever considers different reference types different things, it doesn't matter if they have the same printed name.

All in all, I still think the promising approach to be a dedicated wrapper reference command, as I suggested initially. But that might be very tricky, because using the ref option affects all references in a given list, so there's really no readily available method to mix different results to your conditional in the same list...

Here is one way to do it. It feels a bit like cheating the intended use of the reference structure, but I think it should work as expected. The tricky part is to have access to the label itself, which is not exposed anywhere. But we can get it using the highly versatile label hook from the kernel. In practice, this means we store some extra things with \label (in the default property) so that the conditional of interest can be later tested at the time of reference (when calling \zcref).
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{zref-clever}

\setlist[enumerate, 1]{label=(\roman*)}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

% Making the label itself accessible from the reference.  This only works when
% using \label, not for \zlabel.
\newcommand{\mystorelabel}{}
\AddToHookWithArguments{label}[mystorelabel]{\renewcommand{\mystorelabel}{#1}}
\DeclareHookRule{label}{mystorelabel}{<}{zref-clever}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\makeatletter
\zref@newprop { current@theorem } { \thetheorem }
\zref@addprop { main } { current@theorem }
\NewDocumentCommand { \mythmprefix } { m } {
  \tl_if_eq:eeF
    { \thetheorem } { \zref@extractdefault {#1} { current@theorem } { } }
    { \zref@extract {#1} { current@theorem } }
}

\bool_new:N \l_my_insidetheorem_bool
\AddToHook { env/theorem/begin } {
  \zcsetup { countertype = { enumi = theorem } }
  \bool_set_true:N \l_my_insidetheorem_bool
}
\AddToHook { env/enumerate/begin } {
  \bool_if:NT \l_my_insidetheorem_bool
    {
      \zref@setcurrent { default }
        { \mythmprefix { \mystorelabel } \@currentlabel }
    }
}
\makeatother
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem} \label{thm}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item \label{itm}
    \end{enumerate}
\end{theorem}

Input: \verb|\zcref{itm}|

Output: \zcref{itm}

Desired: theorem (i)

\begin{theorem} \end{theorem}

Input: \verb|\zcref{itm}|

Output: \zcref{itm}

Desired: theorem 1(i)

\paragraph{Regarding sorting}\par

Input: \verb|\zcref{thm,itm}|

Output: \zcref{thm,itm}

Desired: theorems 1~and~1(i)

\end{document}



Although the problem with the printed name of a reference is unsolved. I think this is simply impossible with the current design of zref-clever since the reference would need to change its type depending on the context of \zcref, but reference type is already set once and for all with \label (correct me if I'm wrong). Anyway I will accept the answer.

@Gargantuar Which "problem with the printed name of a reference"? But, yes, the reference type is determined when the label is set, and then fixed for every reference to it. That's the way to ensure a label is consistently referenced to across the document.

Like in my picture, I wanted (i) instead of theorem (i) directly after Theorem 1. But yeah, here I might define myself a reference wrapper which passes noname as an option in the right context. Then again, features like lists of references are not available with this wrapper.

@Gargantuar Ah, I see, I actually thought that was a typo in your MWE and "corrected" it. So you'd like to inhibit the name of the reference according to the same conditional. Yeah, there's no provision for that... You can always inhibit it manually with the noname option. Besides, this would be a bit tacky for lists of labels. This could easily become inconsistent or confusing. For example, for \zcref{thm,itm} should the name be printed or not?...
